# I don't know what to do next after I installed Ubuntu using VMware. It goes to a blank screen

Tags: vmware

I just installed Ubuntu using VMware Player. After I installed it, it goes to a blank screen and asked for my username and password. I typed it in then is says:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)
*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

329 packages can be updated.
73 updates are security updates.

mumsawitch@ubuntu:~$
```

I don't know what to type in next. I tried inputting "yes" but it hanged (or at least I think it did) and started displaying a lot of letter Ys. Ugh. I'm getting frustrated. What should I do

Answer (score 2):

That is a `tty` - a terminal. Press CTRL-ALT-F7 to go back to a graphical interface - or if that is just a black screen, press CTRL-ALT-F1 and type in `sudo startx` and then press Enter..